# ¿Como podría mostrar el promedio notas de mi base datos usando un boton en php?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

tengo problemas para poder mostrar el promedio en mi tabla.
En este caso ya logre ingresar las 4 notas, Con un boton quiero actualizaar el atributo promedio correspondiente a las notas de cada fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he logrado realizar la consulta para que muestre el promedio redondeado que es la siguiente:

```
SELECT ROUND(( Nota1 + Nota2 + Nota3 + Nota4)/4) FROM estudiante;
```

Este  es el codigo de mi clase promedio.php

```
<?php
include ("bd.php");
if (isset($_GET['Id_Alumno']))
{
    $id=$_GET['Id_Alumno'];
    $consulta="SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE Id_Alumno=$id";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado)==1)
    {
        $row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
        $nota1=$row['nota1'];
        $nota2=$row['nota2'];
        $nota3=$row['nota3'];
        $nota4=$row['nota4'];
    }
}
if(isset($_POST["promedio"]))
{
    
    $nota1=$_POST['nota1'];
    $nota2=$_POST['nota2'];
    $nota3=$_POST['nota3'];
    $nota4=$_POST['nota4'];


    $consulta2="SELECT ROUND(( Nota1 + Nota2 + Nota3 + Nota4)/4) FROM estudiante;";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta2);
    
    if(!$resultado)
    {
        die("consulta fallada");
    }
    $_SESSION["message"]="Datos Guardados";
    $_SESSION["message_type"]="success";

    header("Location:index.php");
} 
?>
```

La explicación del primer get es para obtener los datos de la fila que para realizar el promedio.
Y el post para que se muestre en la tabla aqui es donde no sé como realizar el código adecuadamente
Tengo entedido que para que se muestre deberia ser un update, pero como podría mezclar mi consulta dentro del update para toda la columna promedio.
Para cuando yo presione el boton promedio se muestre en la tabla.

Comment: Esto no tiene ni pies ni cabeza. En una query consultas "alumno", en la otra "estudiante". En la segunda query no hay filtro WHERE. Si tienes las cuatro notas ¿necesitas hacer una consulta SQL para sacar la media? ¿por qué no la sacas en PHP? Y si por alguna razón la quieres sacar mediante SQL, ¿por qué no la agregas a la primera query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si en tu el `$_POST["promedio"]` estás recibiendo las cuatro notas del alumno *x* y quieres actualizar el campo `promedio` para dicho alumno, podrías calcularlo con `PHP` (ya que tienes los datos a mano) en lugar de hacerlo con `SQL`.

```
$nota1 = $_POST['nota1'];
$nota2 = $_POST['nota2'];
$nota3 = $_POST['nota3'];
$nota4 = $_POST['nota4'];

$promedio = ($nota1 + $nota2 + $nota3 + $nota4) / 4;
```

Ahora ejecuta la consulta `SQL` para actualizar la bd e ingresar este resultado.
Además, no queda del todo claro pero asumiré que también estás recibiendo el ID del alumno para establecer la relación.

```
$id = $_POST['id_alumno'];

$consulta2 = "UPDATE estudiante SET promedio = $promedio WHERE Id_Alumno = $id";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn,$consulta2);
```